# How can I connect to my machine which is connected to internet via dsl?

Tags: networking, ssh, vnc

I've configured my machine with dyndns.com so that I can use the ssh and vnc

but the problem is, the machine is connected to internet via dsl,. so it uses a network ip address ex (192.168.1.xxx) instead of using the gateway address directly..

I know the gateway ip address (public ip).. but I can not use it to connect to my machine...

How can I do it?
What should I do in order to able to use the gateway so that I can connect to ssh and vnc ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the web administration page of your gateway, and search for "port forwarding" or "virtual server": the gateway need to forward packets to a given port, say port 22, to your particular internal IP address.

I suppose you can select the service from the list, ssh should be there. Then insert the internal IP of your machine in the "Server IP address" text field.

For services not in the list you should select "Custom server", I suppose the dialog will change to let you put in the port number.

For dyndns, your gateway could have the support (see the help or doc of the gateway) or you can use some software on your host to inform dyndns of external IP changes.

Comment: Thanks, please check this : http://postimage.org/image/1ggg7k0dg/ what should I add there ? by the way, the public IP is dynamic so it might change once I restart my router

Comment: @DeaDSouL: I updated the answer, see above.